# Clean up file names in Visual Studio's tabbed document interface?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, editor

Inside a visual studio project I have the following folders (for example)

- foo/
- bar/
- LongFolderName/

When I open up a file in LongFolderName/ the tab gets labeled with `LongFolderName/L...me.ascx` when I'd prefer `LongFileName.ascx` (omitting the name of the folder). Any way to set Visual Studio to ignore the folder name when  labeling the tab?

EDIT: here is what my tab bar looks like:

http://img355.imageshack.us/img355/7040/tabsmn7.png

Notice how the names of my files are truncated past readability. I've got "EventCalendar," "MonthlyEventCalendar," and "WeeklyEventCalendar" and as it stands its rather hard to tell the difference. I know that these files are in UserControls/. How do I get VS to stop telling me?

EDIT:
The name of the file in the **Window | Windows** menu is `longfoldername/longfilename` as is the title of the window if I switch VS to MDI interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tabs Studio add-in](http://www.tabsstudio.com) for Visual Studio that replaces built-in Visual Studio tabs doesn't shorten tab names and has option to remove path from tab name.

Answer (score 2):

longfoldername/longfilename tab name is used in Visual Studio Web Site projects. Maybe it would help if you created a ASP.NET Web Application project in the same folder with a different name and used that project when editing files.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the **Window | Windows...** menuitem, what do the Name and Path fields look like for your open documents?

On my install, the Name fields are just the filenames, exactly what appears in the tabs.

Do the full paths appear in the window titles if you set the Window layout to "Multiple documents"?

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear you can do what you are asking...I have been searching for a while now.

I am assuming you have tried the multiple documents layout...

http://forums.asp.net/t/1285843.aspx

There is the pre-release of vs2010 which may address this:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=922B4655-93D0-4476-BDA4-94CF5F8D4814&displaylang=en

or go to msdn for some videos of it in use.

--