# Remove path from tab name in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I'm opening an individual file in Visual Studio 2010 the file path is displayed in the tab. The name is abbreviated with ellipses. This makes the text of the tab very long and very hard to read. I would like to see just the name of the file.

For VS 2008 there seems to be no way around this except by spending money for a add-on.
([Clean up file names in Visual Studio's tabbed document interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226262/clean-up-file-names-in-visual-studios-tabbed-document-interface))

I wonder if this has improved in VS 2010 and if there is now an option to remove the path from the tab name without installing an add-on?

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't happen in VS2010.  Is that all you want to know?

Comment: Well, for me it still happened in VS2010, how can I change it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The truncating behavior still occurs. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a setting that controls the text on the tabs. It appears the method of truncating has been changed since VS2008, but I don't think it completely resolves your issue.

[image: TabLength]

Answer (score 0):

[Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) take care of this.  You can hover on the tab to get the full path:

[image]