# Remove path from tab name in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, productivity-power-tools

Using this post as a reference, 
[Remove path from tab name in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715426/remove-path-from-tab-name-in-visual-studio-2010) I am trying to remove the path from my tabs in Visual Studio 2015 when you open files that aren't part of the solution itself (like documentation files or scripts).  So I've downloaded the [Productivity Power Tools 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d) but I can't seem to find the option that removes the path.

Anyone know how to do it please?

Edit: Appears that it's mostly files opened from Source Control Explorer that is displaying this behaviour.  Most likely because it's possible to open the same file from multiple branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the best option is to use the File->Open menu and select the files from within the workspace.  Once Visual Studio opens the file, it only displays it's filename without the entire path.

The only downside to this approach is that hovering over the tab title doesn't display the file path.  But it's an acceptable compromise.